# Talend -Extract Month Name from date field

Tags: java, etl, talend

We have Talend tool based on Java code. I am trying to extract month name from date field.

**Input :**

```
date type field  2016-11-01
```

**we tried:**

```
TalendDate.formatDate("MMMM",row1.Date)
```

**Output:**

```
November
```

Comment: So you get what you need with `TalendDate.formatDate`? What is your question?

Comment: No , trying on this issue

Comment: So with *Output:* you mean *Desired output:*? When I tried your expression, it worked like a charm. What is your exact problem?

Comment: my problem exist with Date field . in talend default date is dd/mm/yyyy. but when i changed this to yyyy-mm-dd.  this function is working fine . and now   getting desired  resulset. thanks

Comment: This means the question is not about *extracting* the date but *importing* the date correctly. Please consider next time adding such important details.

Comment: Sure. but  at the  time of posting i was not aware with date field format causing the issue otherwise i would have been posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125604/discussion-between-vickps-and-tobi6).